# Monic group morphism is an injection.

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to prove that a monic group morphism is an injection. Does this follow from the existence of a free group in one generator? Thank you for any thoughts on this.

Comment: In fact, yes. Show that representable functors send monomorphisms to monomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $f:G\to H$ is not injective, try to find two different subgroups of $G$ which are both mapped to the identity in $H$.

Of course, this does not work for monoids, so the idea in that case would in fact be to send the generator $1$ of $\Bbb Z$ to the two elements $a,b\in G$ which have the same image under $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Injections are the monic of the category $\mathsf{Sets}$. You then want to show that the forgetful functor $U \colon \mathsf{Grps} \to \mathsf{Sets}$ from groups to sets preserves monomorphisms.

But $U$ admits a left adjoint (namely the free group functor) and so preserves (small) limits. If you can show that the monic condition can be expressed as a limit, then you are done. I let you show that an arrow is monic if and only if [*some diagram : find it !*] is a limiting cone.